# Find overlapping dates of 2 different tables for each ID In Python / Pandas /Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The 2 tables have multiple date ranges for each ID, the total number of ID around 40k.

Its expected that each ID date range in each table don't overlap, but the overlap happens between the two tables: In this example of 2 different ID's, there is n overlap between the date ranges between table 1 and table 2, so I need to find across the whole dataframe, which records in table 1 overlaps with dates in table 2 for each ID.

**Table 1**

[image: table1]

**Table 2**

[image: l]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

T1 = pd.read_excel('Table1.xslx')
T2 = pd.read_excel('Table2.xslx')

df = pd.merge(T1, T2, how='inner')
print(df)
```

Merging of 2 dataframes gives intersection between them.